# Ajax file upload in laravel webview not working

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, webview

I am making a system in webview where user can change their image.

using ajax , laravel , webview but it's not working showing following error . 
                    
                        
                        
                        
                            
                                profile_picture}}" alt="" width="100"
                                     height="100"
                                     id="user_profile_img">
                            
                            {{$user->name}}
                            Web Developer · Designer · Team Lead
                            
                            
                                 Upload profile Picture
                            
                            Save

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#save_user_profile").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var authorizationToken = $("#authtoken").val();
        var form = document.forms.namedItem("user_profile_form"); // high importance!, here you need change "yourformname" with
        var formData = new FormData(form);


        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Authorization': authorizationToken,
                'device_type': 'android'
            },
            async: true,
            type: 'post',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,

            url: '{{ action('Mobile\UserProfileController@updateUserProfile') }}',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);

                if (result.status) {
                    alert(result.message);
                } else {
                    alert(result.message);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });


    Android.pageParams("Profile", "", "", false, "", "", "");
</script>
```

this is my controller

```
public function updateUserProfile(Request $request)
    {

        $userimg = $request->file('user_profile_picture');
        echo json_encode(['status' => true, 'message' => $_FILES]);
    }
```

Getting following error :

```
{"status":true,"message":{"user_profile_picture":{"name":"","type":"","tmp_name":"","error":4,"size":0}}}
```

pls keep in mind that I am not using it in browser it opening in android webvier or ios webview or any other , but this will be in webview

Answer (score 2):

change

```
    $userimg = $request->file('user_profile_picture');
echo json_encode(['status' => true, 'message' => $userimg]);
```

}

Comment: What should i write here .

Comment: Replacing $_FILES with $userimg is not solutions , I just want to show all about the request , What I am getting in $_FILES means  I am getting nothing in file object show if i will write $userimg this will give me null